# Why does copying files from one partition to another of the same disk take time?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, file-transfer

Applying my general understanding if partitioning is done within the same physical hard drive, copying data from one partition to another should involve only changing indexes to where the GUI representation of files leads, yet we observe a lengthy copying process?

Comment: first, note that reindexing only works when you move a file (not copy; I often make a copy of a file and change the new instance of it, without changing the contents of the original), and secondly only if it remains on the same partition, in the same filesystem instance.

Comment: No, a copy makes a _copy_ -- new files with new index entires. _Moving_ the files on the same partition just adjusts the index as you are suggesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how partitions work. What happens if you're copying from a Linux ext3 partition to a Windows-based NTFS? You can't just change the index, you need to physically move the data. This is also why partitions do not dynamically expand by default.

Data is laid out, ideally, in a single stream for each file, within the bounds of the partition. Just like when you partition a land mass for development, the developers cannot go into other people's area to build on for their master.

There are partitions that will expand when requested, but it still needs the area it's expanding onto to be clear of any other partitions. Copying the data does just that, copy. This is the way disks work for now, until there is a wide-spread, accepted method of automatically just creating symlinks on any sort of copy - I heard that Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8 were planning on this type of feature with Storage Spaces, but I haven't seen it yet to experiment.

Another reason for the slowness is because the drive needs to read from itself at the old location, then write to itself at a new location. On a traditional spinning hard drive, this will take more time, given that it must physically move the disk much more. With an SSD, it is not as bad, but it still requires copying the actual data to different sectors of the SSD. (Credit: Psycogeek)

Comment: *"the drive needs to read from itself at the old location, then write to itself at a new location."* -- You make it sound as if the drive *"itself"* performs the copy operation.  The file copy is under the full control of the CPU.  Sector data is read from the drive into main memory, and then written back out to the drive.  Also your comments about expanding partitions are irrelevant to the the question.

Comment: Correct, but I was trying to simplify it. As for the expanding partitions, I thought of adding a bit *more* information to help out understanding why